# Installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation, upgrade

I have a Gateway desktop with Vista Home Premium. I am trying to upgrade to Windows 7. It will not complete the installation, this is very aggravating! I have been trying for over 3 hours to install it and I won't install!

Comment: Which model? Did you run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor? What error messages, if any, did you get?

Comment: +1. yes run the W7 upgrade advisor...http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15

Comment: Are there any error messages?  As I recall, you can't upgrade from Vista to Windows 7 unless you have Vista SP1 installed.

Comment: What's happening?  "[W]on't install!" isn't very descriptive.  Also note that the upgrade process can take a very long time as it migrates your profile.  [Linky](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/09/microsoft-upgrade-to-windows-7-can-take-up-to-a-day.ars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had issues with Windows 7 installing at my work. The partition table was screwing with it. If the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor doesn't help. Try using GPartEd on it. Delete all of the partitions, and then try installing it.

If you need any more help, let me know with a comment! :)

Comment: If you follow this advice... ***BACKUP FIRST***!!!  This advice will destroy all the data on your system!

Comment: What is a partition? I think I already erased all my data, completely! I still can not install Win7!!!!!!

Comment: David, thanks forthe adice, butI sill cannot install Win7! I didn't really read the instructions, I just put in the Win7 disc and followed the instructions, it gets about three-fourths into completion and stops! Blank screen!

Comment: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php is the link that you need to find the ISO image. Burn the ISO image to a cd. Put the ISO image in the computer. Restart the computer and allow it to boot to the CD. after it boots to the CD, you will have a program to work with. It is pretty easy to delete the partitions. The partitions are how the disc car be divided up into multiple discs. If you would like any more information on a partition refer to the following link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning. They also have a little bit of info about GPartEd at the link.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to listed to @afrazier. Please backup your data first if you have any on there you care about. I thought you didn't care about any of the information when you were reinstalling the OS. +1 to afrazier...

Comment: I have back up disks. I am on my laptop communing to you. I can not use my desk top. Blank screen!

Comment: I am very confused about your previous comment... Please help me understand what is going on and I will try to walk you through it... :D

Comment: I have to leave work soon, so I cannot help much longer... I will be able to help more tomorrow.

Comment: I did not run the Win7 upgrade advisor, I put the Win7 upgrade disk in and followed instructions on the screen. I did the Custom ddownload. Erased everything, that's fine I didn't really have anything important on it! I can not get anything to work, even my PC! It will not complete the download for Win7! That is about as much as I can explain, I am not a PC Geek!

Comment: I think that I really messed up my PC. I can't get anything on it. What an Idiot I am!!!!!!

Comment: Well... If your installation just hangs, then you should use GPartEd like I stated in my answer. Go to the link that I provided and download the file (here is the exact link, the download should start immediately after clicking the link. http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.7.0-4/gparted-live-0.7.0-4.iso/download) Once you download the file, burn it to a CD. Stick the CD in the CD-Rom of the computer you are working on. Restart the computer. The computer should boot to it or ask you to press any to to boot to it. Do it. Delete Partitions. The tool is easy to use.

Comment: If you need more help, let me know. I made it pretty basic. Get to the tool and you will see what I mean on how easy it is. Just remember, you have one objective once your in the GPartED tool, delete all of the partitions. Click on all of the colored areas in the diagram and click delete.

Comment: Also, FYI, you did not delete the partition when you clicked remove during the Windows 7 installation. That doesn't do everything, which is why I am telling you to use GPartEd. GPartEd stands for GNOME Partition Editor if you are wondering. You must use this tool to fix your issue if I am correct about what is wrong with your computer.